# Retrieve the Routerlink as a String?

Tags: angular

Goal:
Retrieve the routerlink after clicking the blue button.
For instance when I have pressed the button "navigate to CustomerDetails Page" of Frank Jose, the 
path or the link will be "app-customer-details/3"

Problem:
is is possible to retrieve the path or the link "app-customer-details/3" inside of the page customer-details.component, without hardcoding the link, as a string?

Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-routerlinks-from-component

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can subscribe to the `url` property of `ActivatedRoute` with would return an array of the subroutes and you would have to concatenate the sub-routes to create the route:

You can do something like this: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-routerlinks-from-component-v9hjsh

You can also take a look at the docs of the ActivatedRoute for more info: 
https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute